# How to get rid of column header background color on sort?

Tags: ngtable

I would like to have the background color of the column header transparent (instead of the light blue in the screenshot below). Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You all have to override or change ng-table.css

```
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-desc,
.ng-table th.sortable.sort-asc {
  background-color: rgba(141, 192, 219, 0.25); <-- remove this or change as per your need
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```